# does scrollorama work horizontally

Tags: jquery

does [scrollorama](http://johnpolacek.github.com/scrollorama/) work horizontally?

it has a duration but that kicks in when the scoll hits a vertical threshold

I would like to use these features on a horizontal scrolling page

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scrollorama is not set up for horizontal scrolling. However, SuperScrollorama is:

`var scrollyStuff = $.superscrollorama({isVertical:false});`

http://johnpolacek.github.com/superscrollorama/

Comment: Please, is there any navigation system for Scrollorama, or i need something like scrollTo.js?

Answer (score 2):

Edit **jquery.scrollorama.js**

**string 102:**

```
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
```

**change to:**

```
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollLeft(),
```